# Display webgrid with rowspan IN MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

How to code webgrid as shown beloW in MVC 3.

```
h1   |   h2  |  h3
-------------------
R11  |  R12  |  R13
     |-------|------
     |  R22  |  R23
-------------------
R22  |  R21  |  R23
     |-------|------
     |  R22  |  R33
```

Middle colmn and 3 rd column spans 2 rows each.

Answer (score 1):

sorry but that kind of requirements it's not possible with Microsoft's WebGrid helper, you just can apply custom text format, style, column name and if can be sortable.

in this case you should go for old way or third party components

and if you want the html, it's like you described "Middle colmun and 3rd colums spans 2 rows each"

```
<table BORDER=1>
<thead>
    <tr>
    <td>H1</td>
    <td>H2</td>
    <td>H3</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2>
        R11
    </td>
    <td>
        R12
    </td>
    <td>
       R13
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        R22
    </td>
    <td>
        R23
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2>
        R22
    </td>
    <td>
        R21
    </td>
    <td>
       R23
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        R22
    </td>
    <td>
        R33
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Hi Zach....I appreciate your answer....But,I want to display that table using webgrid in MVC...

Comment: the answer it's update, sorry but with a webgrid helper you can't do it